# Help from speakers of English wrt Mathematics: "$-x$" reads as "negative $x$", for some measure $x$?

Tags: proof-writing, terminology, article-writing

I am trying to write a paper in English, while not a native English speaker, and struggle with the English text illustrating the equations.

In English, it is correct to write "negative 1" to mean `-1`. By analogy, it should correct to write "the negative Gini coefficient" to mean the Gini coefficient, but taken with the negative sign (for example to build a composite index). And yet, this sounds strange, because the Gini coefficient is always between `0` and `+1`.

The sentence in question is:

> Diversity is expressed with the negative Gini coefficient of the distribution of `C_i`, the number of posts authored by member `i`

The Gini coefficient of a distribution is an index of inequality. In this case, I have a value function, which is a sum of several variables. I want the Gini coefficient to enter it, but I also want it to enter the function with a negative value. Writing the equation is easy, but I am being asked to also provide a paragraph in English.

Speakers of mathematical English, what should I do?

Comment: One would write $-1$ as $-1$, never as "negative $1$". I would pronounce it as "minus one".

Comment: Not sure this helps but if $g$ is the Gini coefficient, maybe you could say "the opposite of the Gini coefficient" or even "the additive inverse of the Gini coefficient" for $-g$, but that might be a bit "overkill".

Comment: This is not a language question, but a question on mathematical notation. Denote by $g$ the Gini coefficient. Then you can easily refer to $-g$ as the "minus Gini coefficient". "negative 1" is probably Spanish?

Comment: As @orion2112, it is probably best use a letter / variable to represent the coefficient, then use that notation.  For example, take $g$ to be the coefficient, then use $-g$.  If you *really* want language for it, you need some kind of possessive / genitive clause.  Either of orion2112's solutions is good, or "the negative of the Gini coefficient" could work.  Personally, I find all of these to be awkward.

Comment: @DietrichBurde "Negative 1" is perfectly cromulent (American) English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really a question about English usage, and would probably be more appropriate to ask on the [ELL SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If I had to say it in text I'd say "the negative of ..." to avoid confusing with "the ... which is negative". I am a native speaker of American English. But I'd prefer to say something like $-g$ where $g$ is the Gini coefficient, or something similar. The issue is that the negative of the quantity doesn't really *mean* anything by itself, it's just the thing that enters into your expression. Thus resolving it with math notation seems the most direct way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Yanko, Lord Shark, Dietrich and especially orion2112. I edited the question to provide an example. I will also look into orion's suggestion. One additional problem is that I cannot assume readers of the paper to be native speakers. I think that probably "additive inverse of the Gini coefficient" might make some people go "huh?".

Comment: I too was brought up to refer to the additive inverse of $1$ (i.e. $-1$) when spoken aloud as "negative one" though I have heard "minus one" spoken by other people before.  At least in my region "negative one" seems to be the more common.

Comment: I would say, "the negative of the Gini coefficient."

Comment: Ian, saulspatz, thank you too. And of course Xander Henderson and JMorawitz. I appear not to have enough karma to upvote your comments, but "the negative of the Gini coefficient" seems clear and not weird to my Italian ears. [In Italian we would say "the Gini coefficient, with a flipped sign" :-) ]

Comment: I would use *negated* not negative, precisely for the reason you point out

Comment: Colloquially, taking 'negative' as a prefix, I would most easily understand "negative the gini coefficient". This is, of course, improper English.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: The tag info for the tag [tag:article-writing] (with which the OP correctly tagged this post) says: "Various aspects of writing mathematics such as style, notation, grammar, frequently used phrases and common mistakes." There's also the [tag:terminology] tag: "Questions on the usage and meaning of words in mathematics [...]". This question clearly falls under those descriptions. I also think that the citizens of this site are more likely to give high-quality advice on this than the average citizen of ELL.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Surely it would be "negative one" not "negative $1$"? (In English, it's "minus one" not "minus $1$".)

Comment: I'd write, "Diversity is expressed by the negative of the Gini coefficient ..."

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It depends on how lazy the author choses to be. Mixed English and numerals is sometimes permissable, sometimes preferred, and sometimes discouraged.

Comment: @XanderHenderson ... and always horrible $\ddot\smile$

Comment: In an article, you are free to use mathematical notation, such as $-x$, instead of writing out, "the negative of $x$", or "the additive inverse of $x$", or expressing "the negation of a statement $p$" using $\lnot p$ (logic).  Similarly in proof-writing.

Comment: "Blah with the sign flipped" is a thing that people say informally in mathematical (American) English, but that's not really appropriate for an article.

Comment: I've nominated this question for reopening. Please read my comment above about the tag descriptions before voting.